# how to create a dynamic selector for append?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

hi guys i need to append data to a div where i cant dynamic the div look at this code

```
<li  class="media_comment'+$post_id+'"></li>
```

now the post_id is a dynamic value that i am joining to my class

now i need to append some data to this

```
 $(.media_comment).append('<li class=" media-top"><?php echo img($user_file_image); ?> <p>'+comment +'</p> <br><a href="#">Like</a> · <a href="#">Reply</a> </li>');
```

i have the same variable post_id avialable in the append function too. but the value is in a loop and i need to only append this in the li where the same post_id is passing which is posting the same data to every li so what can i do to design a dynamic selector ?
is it possible to do this or should i try another approach?

```
$(window).load(function(e){
    // grab the scroll amount and the window height
       loadmore();
       select_likes();

       select_share();
       // get_recieve_friend_requests();
       // get_sent_friend_requests();
    });

 function loadmore(){
          var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
          alert(lastID);

              jQuery.ajax({
                  type:'POST',

                  url:'<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>',
                   data: {id:  lastID },
                      dataType: 'json', 


                  beforeSend:function(data){
                      $('.load-more').show();
                  },
                  success:function(data){

                         var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
                         var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);


                         if (json=="") {
                          $("#bottom").append('<div class="btn btn-default col-md-6" >'+'No More Results'+'</div>');
                          $("#Load_more_data").hide();

                         }else{

                           $postID=json[json.length-1].id;

              $('.load-more').attr('lastID', $postID);

                $.each(json, function (key, data) {


   var post_id=data.id;

    // alert(data_id);
    var post_status=data.status;
     var status_image=data.status_image;
    var multimage=data.multimage;

                             if(!post_status=="" && !status_image==""){
                              alert(post_id);
                               $("#status_data").append('<div class="panel-footer "  onload="select_comment('+post_id+');"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><a href="#">13 people</a> like this</div></div><ul class="media-list"><li  class="media_comment" id="comment_div'+post_id+'"></li><li class="media"><div class="media-left media-top"><?php echo img($user_file_image); ?></div><div class="media-body"><div class="input-group"><form action="" id="form_content_image"><textarea name="textdata" id="content_comment_image" cols="25" rows="1"  class="form-control message"  placeholder="Whats on your mind ?"></textarea><button type="submit" id="comment_button_image" onclick="comment_here_image('+post_id+');">Comment</button></form></div></div></li></ul></div></div>');
                             } 
                        });
                  }
              }
            });
          }
function select_comment(post_id)
{

  // alert(post_id);
  var Post_id=post_id;
  var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
 jQuery.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url:'<?php echo base_url("user/select_comment"); ?>',
                  data: {Post_id:Post_id,User_id:User_id},
                  dataType: 'json', 
                  success:function(data)
                  {
                    var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
                         var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
                         $.each(json, function (key, data) {
                          var comment=data.comment;
                          var post_id=data.post_id;
                          $post_id=post_id;
                          $("#comment_post_id").attr('value',$post_id);
                             $(#comment_div).append('<li class=" media-top"><?php echo img($user_file_image); ?> <p>'+comment +'</p> <br><a href="#">Like</a> · <a href="#">Reply</a> </li>');
                  });
                }
          });

}
```

here is the loop.

Comment: post the loop too.

Comment: check the edited @Jai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: (try to update the loop something along this lines..)

```
success:function(data)
{
  var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
       var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
       $.each(json, function (key, data) {
        var comment=data.comment;
        var post_id=data.post_id;
        var mediaID = '.media_comment' + post_id;
        $( mediaID ).append('<li class=" media-top"><?php echo img($user_file_image); ?> <p>'+comment +'</p> <br><a href="#">Like</a> · <a href="#">Reply</a> </li>');

});
```

when you loop over json object try to insert something like this there,, if that code is on the php side ofcorse..

```
$sel = ".media_comment$post_id";
$img = img($user_file_image);
$com = $comment;

echo "$($sel).append('<li class='media-top'>$img <p>$com</p> <br><a href='#'>Like</a><a href='#'>Reply</a> </li>');";
```

Comment: it gave syntax error "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .media_comment$post_id" @oserk

Comment: is the function `select_comment` in your template (php) file or is it in some javascript file?

Comment: its a function in my controller in codeigniter. @oserk